# Best folder convention for integration tests in java project

Tags: java, maven, testing

I am creating a Microservices application with java Spring Boot and Maven. As I am new in Java world, would like to know the best folder/filename convention to my integration tests. I know that maven convention says we should segregate the two by suffix "Test" and "IT", but should the two be in the same package?

Comment: As usual a `*Test.java` is a unit test which should be located into the appropriate package but a `*IT.java` is an integration test can be located into a different package...but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your integration tests as a separate maven module.

```
parent-pom.
├── module-a
├── module-b
├── ...
└── integration-tests
```

Frameworks like spring and quarkus are using this convention.

[Quarkus](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus)
[Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)